# Can ECN OctaFx broker (with floating spread) charge spread more than it is shown on the screen in case of high volatility?

Tags: trading, foreign-exchange, broker

I sold 10 lots while the market was going up (and continued going up for 5 mins), the spread was 1.6 as shown on the screen, however the broker charged me for 13 pips of spread instead, even though the market kept going up which gives an impression of a lot of buyers. His excuse was that we are not able to execute all the positions on the price you see on MT4. Is this normal?

Comment: Run as fast as you can if you smell s**t from broker.
As preventive measure I would never consider every broker with MT and fees for money withdraw.

Answer (score -1):

Thats definitely not OK, but they would win a lawsuit - slippage... They are here for clients who don't know what a spread is.

You are not doing baby volumes - 10lots is a good volume (100k lots) checkout Interactive Brokers.

I use them for stocks and I'm more than happy.